# Get Highest Answer Rate Question - Leetcode - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to solve the following Leetcode SQL question:

Question Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/get-highest-answer-rate-question/

Description:

Table: SurveyLog

[image]

The answer rate for a question is the number of times a user answered the question by the number of times a user showed the question.

**Write an SQL query to report the question that has the highest answer rate. If multiple questions have the same maximum answer rate, report the question with the smallest question_id.**

The query result format is in the following example.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
WITH Answers AS (
SELECT question_id, COUNT(question_id) AS ANSWER_COUNT
FROM SurveyLog
WHERE action = 'answer'
GROUP BY question_id),

A AS (SELECT question_id, COUNT(question_id) AS SHOW_COUNT
FROM SurveyLog
WHERE action = 'show'|'skip'
GROUP BY question_id),

B AS (SELECT Answers.question_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Answers.question_id ORDER BY IFNULL((Answers.ANSWER_COUNT/A.SHOW_COUNT), 0) DESC) AS 'Rank' 
FROM Answers
INNER JOIN A ON A.question_id = Answers.question_id
ORDER BY 'Rank' ASC, Answers.question_id ASC)

SELECT DISTINCT question_id AS survey_log FROM B 
LIMIT 1;
```

The code passes one testcase below:
[image]

But it fails other testcases:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it is not passing all test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try using windows function to calculate both answer_count and show_count.

```
WITH Answers AS (
SELECT *,
    COUNT(CASE action WHEN 'show' THEN action END) OVER (PARTITION BY question_id ORDER BY question_id) AS show_count,
    COUNT(answer_id) OVER (PARTITION BY question_id ORDER BY question_id) AS answer_count
FROM survey_log
),
A AS (
SELECT question_id,  
    MAX(answer_count)/MAX(show_count) AS ranked
FROM Answers
GROUP BY question_id
)
SELECT question_id
FROM A
WHERE ranked = (SELECT MAX(ranked) FROM A)
;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c506fb7ef06e7c109bd40a83877713b)